# PHPUnit watchers : how to prevent multiple task execution when saving multiple files at once?

Tags: phpstorm, file-watcher

I have set up a watcher in PHPStorm which triggers the execution of a Grunt task when one of my PHP files is changed. This runs all well, however when I modify mutiple files at one (for instance when replacing a string in several files) the Grunt task is executed as many times as the number of files that have been modified.

I would only need it to be executed once, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

File Watcher is triggered for **every** watched file -- that's what they were made for.

Your options are limited here -- either run your Grunt tasks manually from IDE (be it existing Grunt integration .. or via External Tools etc -- you can assign shortcuts to specific targets/entries) .. or use external watching/processing.